# Including the Year and Months instead of just "xxx Days ago"

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently using `<?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?>` to display something like `22 Days ago` for the date on my posts but when a post is very old, like over a year it could display something like `556 days ago` instead of something like `1 year ago` or `3 years ago`

How do I get it to display in that format instead of just counting the days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a function to calculate the seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, years,...

and then add a filter to `the_time`:

```
add_filter('the_time', 'your function');
```

if you need a function to calculate the time, in this post of Jason Bobich you have a good one: [A better way to add time ago to your wordpress](http://www.jasonbobich.com/wordpress/a-better-way-to-add-time-ago-to-your-wordpress-theme/)

Comment: Please write the answer in your answer

Comment: That's a lot of code to copy. That author deserves some traffic to his blog.

Comment: @adityamenon is right, If it were my code, I will prefer someone links it instead of paste it

Comment: @adityamenon: Yet links aren't answers. Either extract the relevant pieces and cite the blog post, or leave a comment instead! "How do I get to the post office?" "I don't know; ask that person over there instead" is not answering the question posed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's better now?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit S.O makes our lives *too easy* already, as it is; a little jogging around to find the post office shouldn't be a problem :D

Comment: @adityamenon: It's a Q&A and not a search engine, though. You don't have to agree that that's what it _should be_ but, regardless, that's what it _is_!